# Bazel: how to specify --define in file?

Tags: bazel

I hope this is a simple question :) In bazel, I can select a `config_setting` by specifying `--define K=V` passed from the command line. How can I create a library in my BUILD.bazel that "sets" this `config_setting` without the need to specify it from command line?

Comment: .bazelrc named config is one option: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#option-defaults

Comment: Maybe I don't see it but is there a way to set defaults for specific target?

Answer (score 1):

Defaults for flags can be set a [.bazelrc](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/guide.html#bazelrc) file, for example:

```
build --define=VERSION=0.0.0-PLACEHOLDER
build --define=FOO=1
```

You can also have configuration sets too:

```
build:bar --define=VERSION=0.0.0-PLACEHOLDER
build:bar --define=FOO=1
```

The above would only become active when passing the `--config=bar` flag.

Flags passed on the command line will take precedence over those in the `.bazelrc` file.

It's worth mentioning though, that changing define values will cause bazel to analyze everything again, which depending on the graph may take some time, but only affected actions will be executed.

Comment: So basically instead of passing `--define` from command line I now have to pass `--config`? :D Or is there a way to override defaults for specific target?

Comment: this is what I'm curious about too, if you know apriori that a particular rule instantiation should always be associated with a particular config setting for one of its dependencies how would one make that target couple to a particular config value directly in the BUILD file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Some rules have an [`env`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.0.0/be/common-definitions.html) argument, so you can do f.e.:

```py
sh_binary(
  name = "target",
  ...
  env = {
    "K": "V"
  }
)
```